# Set permissions for existing folders and files in ProgramData with WiX Toolset

Tags: windows, permissions, wix, wix-extension, wix3.10

I've inherited a project that uses WIX Toolset (3.10.3) to build the installation package. The application downloads and stores shared data in `c:\ProgramData\Vendor\ApplicationName`. This path is however not created during the installation, but rather during the execution of the application itself, whenever the path is requested for the first time.

I've now discovered a permissions related problem that occurs when multiple Windows users uses the application. Whenever the application downloads new data files from back-end, it's the current windows user that gets "Full control" permissions for those files. When someone else logs in with another Windows account, they only have read permissions to those files. And these mixed permissions causes problems when the application tries to keep the local files synchronized with back-end.

Since the application doesn't require elevated priviliges, I have to correct this during the installation. As a first step, I've now made sure that the `c:\ProgramData\Vendor\` folder is created during installation, and that it gets correct permissions with `<util:PermissionEx User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />`. Since these permissions are inherited, it will solve the problem for all users doing a fresh install.

The problem is that the permissions are only inherited by folders/files created **after** the installation. This means that users who upgrades from a previous version will still have data files left with mixed permissions. I therefore need to make sure that all existing folders and files gets the new permissions during installation. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, this is how I solved it. Hope it can help someone else in the future.

First, I added the following things to the wxs file for the MSI:

```
<Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="ProgramDataVendorFolder" Name="MyVendor">
        <!--This will create the \ProgramData\MyVendor\MyProductName\ folder. -->
        <Directory Id="ProgramDataAppFolder" Name="MyProductName" />
    </Directory>
</Directory>

<DirectoryRef Id="ProgramDataAppFolder">
<Component Id="CmpCreateCommonAppDataFolderWithPermissions" Guid="13ae94b7-9ef5-4181-bfa9-933844a13418" Permanent="yes">
  <CreateFolder>
    <!--This will ensure that everyone gets full permissions to the folder that we create in the ProgramData folder. -->
    <util:PermissionEx User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
  </CreateFolder>
</Component>  
</DirectoryRef>
```

And then included it:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="$(var.ProductName)" Level="1">
    <!--Add folder -->
    <ComponentRef Id="CmpCreateCommonAppDataFolderWithPermissions" />
</Feature>
```

These three things made sure that all users had full access to the folder in ProgramData, even if the folder already exists.

But changing the permissions will not be enough, if file virtualisation is already active due to previous permissions problems. To turn off file virtualisation, I added an app.manifest to my executable with:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

Keep in mind that if the previously used VirtualStore contains files that are important, they will not automatically appear in the ProgramData folder.

More info regarding file/registry virtualization can be found here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mrsnrub/2010/08/11/uac-virtualization-allowing-standard-users-to-update-a-system-protected-area/

Comment: This worked well for me.  Note: you do not want to directly use the name of a special user group, like "Authenticated Users" as these are different on localized versions of Windows.  Instead, there are special hard-coded strings in wix to represent these special users.  I.e. for "Authenticated Users", it would be "AuthenticatedUser".  See these related posts for details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1535494/495262
https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/mailman/message/20188763/